# Trying to get enviroment variables on production gets undefined in React

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

Well after 2 days of reading I gonna open my own question.

I got an .env file containing just 1 variable:

`REACT_APP_IMAGES_ROUTE = http://.../uploads/instancia/`

And an .env.production file with same variable but diferent value:

`REACT_APP_IMAGES_ROUTE = 'imagenes/`

When I run yarn start the variable on .env works perfectly, but when I make a yarn build and upload it to my server the variable declared on .env.production returns undefined.

react-scripts build is supposed to compile .env.production or am I wrong?

Thank in advance

Comment: Is there any specific documentation you are following? Please update here. Or please post your build file

Comment: Just CRA basic docs -> https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

I'm using the varible on components like this:
`process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGES_ROUTE`